# Add Error Message If Criteria Doesn't Match

Tags: excel, vba

Look for (HERE) in below code for line I'm talking about.

Is it possible to setup an error message if it doesn't find any criteria "Active" in Column D?
I tried inputting an `on error goto` but it gave the msgbox when there were no "Active" projects in column D.  But as soon as there was an "Active" Cell it would error out and not finish the code.

I did use a `Exit Sub` and `Resume` but still didn't work.

```
Const cCrit As Variant = "D"      ' Criteria Column Letter/Number
Const cCols As String = "C:J"     ' Source/Target Data Columns
Const cFRsrc As Long = 15         ' Source First Row

Dim ws1 As Worksheet              ' Source Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet              ' Target Workbook
Dim rng As Range                  ' Filter Range, Copy Range
Dim lRow As Long                  ' Last Row Number
Dim FRtgt As Long                 ' Target First Row
Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult      ' Message Box
Dim Error1 As VbMsgBoxResult      ' Message Box for Errors

' Create references to worksheets.
With ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Future Project Hopper")
    Set ws2 = .Worksheets("CPD-Carryover,Complete&Active")
End With

Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to run the Macro?", vbYesNo, "Run Macro")

If Answer <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

' In Source Worksheet
With ws1
    ' Clear any filters.
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    ' Calculate Last Row.
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cCrit).End(xlUp).row
    ' Calculate Filter Column Range.
    Set rng = .Cells(cFRsrc, cCrit).Resize(lRow - cFRsrc + 1)
    ' Make an offset for the filter to start a row before (above) and
    ' end a row after (below).
    With rng.Offset(-1).Resize(lRow - cFRsrc + 3)
        ' Filter data in Criteria Column.
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Active"
    End With
    ' Create a reference to the Copy Range.
  **(HERE)**  Set rng = .Columns(cCols).Resize(rng.Rows.Count).Offset(cFRsrc - 1) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    ' Clear remaining filters.
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    End With

' Calculate Target First Row.
FRtgt = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, cCrit).End(xlUp).row + 1
' Copy Range and paste to Target Worksheet and clear contents of future project hopper
rng.Copy
ws2.Columns(cCols).Resize(1).Offset(FRtgt - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
rng.Rows.ClearContents


Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = .Columns(cCols).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).Offset(cFRsrc - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No criteria found! Exiting sub"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: It ends the sub but doesn't give the message nor leave the data in the column.